# BindException with message "Address already in use" during Fredhopper Installation

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I am trying to install Fredhopper on a Linux environment. When I am using the command bin\setup-cluster in Install Index and Live Servers (Step 4 in below reference link), it generates a BindException in the log giving message as "Address already in use". I am following the steps listed on the following link:

https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Install+Fredhopper+with+Deployment+Package (login required)

Please provide some pointers on the same as I am not able to find any links pertaining to the above issue on internet.

Comment: "Address already in use" sounds like a port conflict - I wouldn't know which one though

Comment: Could you add some details:
1. Which log is reporting the error?
2. Are all the ports that Fredhopper uses available? The learningcenter article about "Ports in use" mentions them, and you can use `netstat -anp` to check if any other process uses them already.

Comment: Hi Frank, I solved the issue there was some issue with my Java installation. Thanks for your input.